# How can I multiply an array of text with an array of Boolean values in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

I have a array of values that are states {"OH","VA","CA"} and an array of Boolean values {TRUE, FALSE, TRUE} and want to concatenate all the states that correspond to TRUE, so in this example my result would be "OHCA." Company policy does not allow the use of VBA (dumb, I know), so I'm trying to use an array formula. Any idea how to make this work?

Comment: Do you mean you have a **range** of cells with OH, VA and CA and a **range** of cells with True, False, True?

Comment: Why are we talking "Arrays" when we are definitely not talking VBA? You'll need to clarify what you are doing in excel front end terms to get an excel front end answer.

Comment: If you are on Excel 2016 or Office 365, you can use the [TEXTJOIN Function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TEXTJOIN-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c)

Answer (score 3):

As an array formula with CSE,

```
=CONCAT(IF({TRUE,FALSE,TRUE}, {"OH","VA","CA"}, TEXT(,)))
```

Comment: I always wondered why they had the `concat` function when they had the shorter &.  I am assuming `=&CONCAT(IF({1,0,1},{"OH","VA","CA"},TEXT(,)))` will not work.

Comment: As an array formula it should work. As a calculated result, there is no difference between TRUE ans 1 or FALSE and 0 in a worksheet. However, in some array maths, a boolean must be double unaried (as with SUMPRODUCT) in order to complete a maths operation.

Answer (score 0):

I allow myself to suggest this answer, that gives an answer to the title question and not to the question text because it shows in top results and I suspect it is a common topic.

A simple and elegant way to do this:
=FILTER({"OH","VA","CA"}, {TRUE,FALSE,TRUE})

For the text case, just apply CONCAT() to the above suggestion.